# flutter : shared preference issue

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to add a shared preference to my application to save the user's data for the next login but I get an error and I have an infinite loop of loading data and my application crashed after this loop.

this is the error which I get

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   setState() called after dispose(): _SplashScreenState#e691a(lifecycle
>   state: defunct, not mounted) E/flutter ( 2799): This error happens if
>   you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer
>   appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer
>   includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code
>   calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. E/flutter (
>   2799): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening
>   to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to
>   check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState()
>   to ensure the object is still in the tree. E/flutter ( 2799): This
>   error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called
>   because another object is retaining a reference to this State object
>   after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks,
>   consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

and this is the method to get preference in my splash screen

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isLog = prefs.getBool("islog");
    print(this.mounted);
    if(this.mounted){
    if (isLog == true) {
      setState(() {
      String email = prefs.getString("email");
      String pass = prefs.getString("pass");
        signIn(email, pass);

         });
     } 
     }else {
      if(!mounted)
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  signIn(String email, String pass) async {
    var res = await userProvider.login(email, pass);

    var user = userProvider.user.tourist;
    if (res is FailedRequest) {
      Dialogs.showErrorDialog(context, message: res.message, code: res.code);

    } else if (user == true) {
      print("Shared ***********************************************");
      await appProvider.countryList();
      await appProvider.activityList();
      await appProvider.tourGuideList();

     setState(() {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomTourist()));
      });
    }
```

and this is my splash screen widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
    init();
    return Container(
        child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              foregroundDecoration: !AppTheme.isLightTheme
                  ? BoxDecoration(
                      color:
                          AppTheme.getTheme().backgroundColor.withOpacity(0.4))
                  : null,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/introduction.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: SizedBox(),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: AppTheme.getTheme().dividerColor,
                            offset: Offset(1.1, 1.1),
                            blurRadius: 10.0),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/appIcon.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: SizedBox(),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 48, right: 48, bottom: 8, top: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 48,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppTheme.getTheme().primaryColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: AppTheme.getTheme().dividerColor,
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          offset: Offset(4, 4),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: InkWell(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => IntroductionScreen()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Get started",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my login method which use to set preference for the user

```
signIn() async {
    var res = await userProvider.login(
        _userNameController.text, _passwordController.text);
    var user = userProvider.user.tourist;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (res is FailedRequest) {
      Dialogs.showErrorDialog(context, message: res.message, code: res.code);

    } else if (user == true) {
      print("Signing in success");
      await appProvider.countryList();
      await appProvider.activityList();
      await appProvider.tourGuideList();

      setState(() {
        prefs.setBool("islog", true);
        prefs.setString('pass', userProvider.user.password);
        prefs.setString('email', userProvider.user.email);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(widget._context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomTourist()));
      });

    }
```

so can anyone help me with my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setState` in an `async` method named '`signIn()'` without checking whether the widget is alive or not.

### Proper solution

You need to set up a well-defined state management system for your app. Read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for more info.

### Quick solution

**Steps:**

1. Add a `boolean` variable in your state class to identify whether the widget is alive or not.
2. Set the boolean as false on [dispose()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) callback.
3. Before calling [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) after an async operation, check whether the
   widget is alive or not.

Comment: kindly can you do this steps in code because i'm new in flutter and i feel some confuse , sorry

Comment: where you got stuck?

Comment: Use a stateful widget and add the boolean variable into your state class

Comment: like this ?
bool alive;
void dispose() {
    alive=false;
    super.dispose();
  }

Comment: @MariamYounes yes

Comment: in which part i should put the dispose ?

Comment: inside your stateful widget

Comment: init sync(){}
signIn(email,pass) sync{}
dispose(){}
in this arrange ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208621/discussion-between-mariam-younes-and-darish).

Comment: no i sent what happen in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208621/discussion-between-mariam-younes-and-darish